# Is there an easy way to convert from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop, system.net.mail

The title pretty much says it all. I have an Outlook interop `MailItem`. I'd like to create a `System.Net.Mail` `MailMessage` from the `MailItem`, modify a few properties (such as the sender), and then send it. Is this something that must be done manually, or do either of these libraries (or a third party library) provide a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that.  And it probably won't be easy to fetch attachments.

Comment: @SLaks For attachments is there any reason the suggestion here wouldn't work? [Programmatically Save Attachments from Outlook E-Mail Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268754.aspx)

Comment: Yes; that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailItem` from Outlook and `MailMessage` from the .NET Framework are very different things.

You need to do a lot of work manually:

1. Copy simple properties like subject, sender, to/cc/bcc lists.
2. Fetch all body formats and create new bodies in `MailMessage`.
3. Fetch and store attachments from `MailItem` using temporary files or memory streams.
4. Create new attachments for `MailMessage` using stored data from the previous point.